# Error - Paragraph ended before \OT1\. was complete

Tags: bibtex

I was writing some more references in my bib file when suddenly I ran into this issue. I guess it is probably because I was using special characters. However, even after deleting the entry or changing its name to have none special characters I still get the error. Is there a way aroud it? Does bibtex store its information somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: delete the bbl file (the output from bibtex) and the aux file (the input to bibtex) then re-run latex and bibtex

Answer (score 2):

You have somewhere in the text accent \. and letter after it.

Let we suppose that in the text you have \.a

Then change it to \.{a}

Comment: This may be a possibility, but after 4 years of the original post's existence this "answer" is  at best a comment.